# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$query = $conn->prepare(¨SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN billetera.status=1 THEN billetera.monto ELSE 0 END) AS monto_a_favor, users.*
                                             FROM billetera
                                             INNER JOIN users ON billetera.id_usuario=users.id
                                             WHERE billetera.status=1
                                             GROUP BY id
                                             ORDER BY monto_a_favor
                                             DESC¨);
```

Pero el Navegador me da el siguiente resultado:
*Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column*

He estado viendo unas excepciones nuevas en este tema pero no comprendo como debo solucionar mi consulta para que no de error.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("
  SELECT id,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN billetera.status=1 
        THEN billetera.monto
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS monto_a_favor
    FROM billetera
    INNER JOIN users ON billetera.id_usuario=users.id
    WHERE billetera.status=1
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY monto_a_favor
    DESC
");
```

El mensaje de error te indica que debes hacer uso del campo de agregación `id`.

Comment: Si correcto pero ese mensaje solo me sale en la salida al navegador porque desde PHPmyADMIN si me arroja los resultados sin problema..!!! Esa sentencia la estaba utilizando con MySQLi pero estoy cambiando a PDO y me encuentro con este tipo de problemas..!

Comment: He intentado como sugiere y me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de error.! y logicamente al hacer el la prueba en PhpMyAdmin la salida es correcta..!

Comment: he solucionado siguiendo estos pasos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by